# How to install mtd-utils on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation

I have already tried the following code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mtd-utils
```

But it does not work! It says:

```
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~$ mtd-utils
mtd-utils: command not found
elans@elans-TravelMate-P446-M:~$ mtd
No command 'mtd' found, but there are 18 similar ones
mtd: command not found
```

What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

If `apt-get install mtd-utils` didn’t complain, then it worked. But the `mtd-utils` package doesn’t contain the commands you’re trying to use; try `mtdinfo` instead (as root). You can see the contents of the package by running `dpkg -L mtd-utils`.

Comment: When I do `sudo mtdinfo` it says: `mtdinfo: error!: cannot get MTD information
         error 2 (No such file or directory)`. Even if I change to the package directory `/usr/sbin` it gives the same error.

Comment: That shows that it’s installed. If you want it to do something useful then you need to use it properly: `mtdinfo -a`, or something like `mtdinfo /dev/mtd0`; `mtdinfo -h` will show basic usage information.